# MapInfo Universal Translator turning integer columns to decimal

Tags: shapefile, mapinfo, fme-form, tab, translation

I've got a TAB file that I am using FME Universal Translator in MapInfo 12.5 to turn into a SHP.

The input TAB file has a variety of columns, some are floats and some are integers.

The output shapefile has the same fields, but it turns the integer fields into decimal(11,0). The float fields remain floats.

Is there a way to get the output to have the integer fields just like the input?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the ESRI Shape format doesn't support SmallInt and Integer.

> Shape does not support small integer (16bit) or integer (32bit) data types. Instead, it supports a number(x,y) data type. The equivalent data types are:
>
> - smallint (16bit): number(6,0)
> - integer (32bit): number(11,0)

[FME Shape Reader/Writer documentation](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_ReadersWriters/FME_Readers_Writers.htm#shape/shape.htm)

So the answer seems to be: No

Comment: Well, no. It's says that shape files are using Number(11,0) in stead of Integer. Not sure how big a difference that is. I also wonder if MapInfo Pro by default will interpret Number(11,0) as Integer if you import a Shape file into MapInfo Pro

Comment: Well, I think that dBase format does not define integers. It has just Numeric and 11 digits with zero digits after decimal separator is an integer http://www.dbase.com/KnowledgeBase/int/db7_file_fmt.htm.

Answer (score 1):

When I asked Pitney Bowes support this question, I heard the following (same as Peter's response, essentially).

"This issue is working as designed as there is no equivalent type to what MIPro uses for an Integer in dBase IV, so these fields are getting mapped to Numeric (Decimal) or Float types. Unfortunately there is no work around for this at this time."